# skeleton tracking: Open Source equivalent to closed source NITE?

Tags: ros, kinect, skeletal-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi every one,
i'm now woking on some project concerning to skeleton tracking with kinect. However, for a company, NITE is closed and needs a commercial license.I want to know whether or not there is any group working on an equivalent or similar open library in order to make the cooperation.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10776/skeleton-tracking:-open-source-equivalent-to-closed-source-nite?/) by [nhanndt](https://answers.ros.org/users/249/nhanndt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2011-07-31

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-31**:
Try and put more information in the title so that readers don't have to click through to know if they have relevant information to provide.  I changed this one for you : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is currently a collaboration between Willow, TUM, Leuven (in the internship program) to make this happen, hopefully very soon this can be released.
Cedric, Kurt or Caroline might be able to tell you more about it, as I just joined the effort.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2011-08-03**:
This is the [document](http://lists.willowgarage.com/pipermail/pr2_beta_program/attachments/20110525/48d091ca/attachment-0001.pdf).

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-08-03**:
I'm interested in which document this was? I had 2 thesis students working on this and currently one internship, perhaps it's one of their documents.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2011-08-02**:
I'd be very interested in knowing the scope of the project. The best I could find searching the web was a document from KUL stating:  "Human motion tracking (like OpenNI tracker) based on PR2 native sensors (without a kinect!)". TIA.